# Disconnect specific user from a channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a **discord.py bot** and I'm trying to **disconnect a specific user from a voiceChannel**.
I saw in the doc the method `voice_client` from `discord.guild` and I tried to get all the voice_clients connected to the guild's voice_channels.In order to search for a specific voice_client later and use the voice_clients.disconnect() method to disconnect it.
But `guild.voice_client` return **none** maybe there is a better way to do it, or am I missing something ?

Here is a chunk of my code

```
async def vc(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.id == myguild:
            print(guild.voice_client) #return none
            for vClients in guild.voice_client: #raise error (none is non-iterable)
                await ctx.send("thing")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
async def kick(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has been kicked from {user.voice.channel.mention}')
    await user.move_to(None)
```